# Why does a solution of a pyomo lp model sometimes violate hard constraints?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, pyomo

I have a pyomo concrete lp model with several hard and soft constraints. When solving it with the IBM ILOG CPLEX solver sometimes some hard constraints are violated even though the solver says the solution is feasible.

First I thought there is a problem with the parallel mode with cplex and tried running the optimization on a single core. But the problem still occurs.
I also tried different solvers like gurobi and cbc, but still the same problem.
I could not find a pattern when the hard constraints are disregarded and it appears to occur somehow randomly.

Could there be an issue with having to little ram to perform the optimization?

Has anyone had the same issue?

EDIT: Testing different values for cplex scale parameter and mip emphasis switch helped. Also found a bug in my code. Now everything works.

Comment: Apart from tolerances, a feasible solution should be feasible. Sometimes poorly scaled models may show (relatively small) infeasibilities due to the interplay of scaling and feasibility tolerances.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen how do I know if my model is poorly scaled?

Comment: By looking at the magnitudes of the coefficients.

Comment: In what way are your constraints violated? Are they almost feasible (e.g. binary variables having values like 0.000001 or 0.99999999) or something else more clearly violated?

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick I recognized that there is also sometimes the problem that binary variables have values like you mentioned. What could be the problem? How are values like 0.9999999 interpreted?

Comment: Very simple. 0.9999999 is within the tolerance of being considered as 1. If that is a problem for you, just round the results to 0 or 1 in your answer. If that then breaks some constraint then you probably have a poorly scaled or ill-conditioned problem.

Comment: Thank you @TimChippingtonDerrick ! Rounding the variables' values to the next integer helped!

Comment: How did you manage to model soft constraints? I did not find any class or subclass of constraints. Sorry if this questions appears silly to you, i am quite fresh to the topic.

Comment: @ChrisChross there is no specific class of constraints needed for that. The modeling of a soft constraint is achieved by introducing a new decision variable into your hard constraint that allows some deviation from "the right side of the constraint". These new dicision variables are therefore called "slack variables" and are normally added to the objective function. One does that, because one is interested in minimizing the slack theses variables allow. Hope that clears it up for you.